# Xpath Query to provide a comma-delimited output

Tags: xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Envelope> 
   <Body> 
      <RetrieveChangeKeysListResponse message="Success"> 
         <keys> 
            <ChangeID type="String">C10286</ChangeID> 
         </keys> 
         <keys> 
            <ChangeID type="String">C10296</ChangeID>
         </keys> 
      </RetrieveChangeKeysListResponse> 
   </Body> 
</Envelope>
```

From the above xml file, output for the below xpath query is giving the values without delimiter.

*Query:*

```
/Envelope/Body/RetrieveChangeKeysListResponse/keys/ChangeID/text()
```

*Output:* `C10286C10296`

How can I get the output with a delimiter between the values.

Example: (`C10286,C10296`)

Need your help in this.

Thanks and regards

Riyas Hussain A

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have two `ChangeID` nodes and if you call `XPATH` as

```
/Envelope/Body/RetrieveChangeKeysListResponse/keys/ChangeID/text()
```

then it will output all the values by concatenating together.

So Call `XPATH` as

```
/Envelope/Body/RetrieveChangeKeysListResponse/keys/ChangeID
```

and then `concat()` the value that is `text()` as you like.

### UPDATED:

Using XSLT 1.0, you can do this way:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/Envelope/Body/RetrieveChangeKeysListResponse/keys/ChangeID"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ChangeID">
        <xsl:if test="position()='1'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'('"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position()=last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(text(),',')"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="')'"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Output:

(C10286,C10296)

Comment: Hi Charan, Thanks for your reply. Can you please give the exact query because i am completely new to this.

Comment: @user2091573: Updated. Refer the answer

Comment: Hi Charan, We are using a automated tool to read the xml file. so we need to single line xpath query as /Envelope/Body/RetrieveChangeKeysListResponse/keys/ChangeID/text() inorder to get the output. Can't we achieve this in one line query?

Comment: @user2091573: As far as I know, there is no way to achieve in one line XPATH.

Comment: @user2091573: which version of XPath are you using? What you need is not possible with XPath 1.0, but it should be possible with XPath 2.0 that has a `for` loop statement

Comment: @MiMo : i am not sure bout the version of XPath. If its possible for you to get me the query with for loop statement so that i can test in my tool.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

**string-join((/Envelope/Body/RetrieveChangeKeysListResponse/keys/ChangeID),',')**

Output:

**String='C10286,C10296'**