# Xpath insert "," after every li

Tags: xpath, domxpath

I have a piece of code and XPath to export it. the code is:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="tags expandable">
    <li><a class="search__link" href="domain.com">office</a></li>
    <li><a class="search__link" href="domain.com">space</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and the Xpath is :

```
//ul[contains(concat (" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " tags expandable ")]
```

this Xpath export data is like this: "office space"
but I want to insert "," after each li and I want the export like this: "office, space,"

Comment: I thing answer is [Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982320/xpath-query-to-provide-a-comma-delimited-output)

Comment: @superup I think it is not the answer for my case

Comment: There is an answer in the link above that uses `string-join`. You can apply that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xpath Query to provide a comma-delimited output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982320/xpath-query-to-provide-a-comma-delimited-output)

Comment: @MathiasMüller unfortunately not, because I have to use Xpath 1

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this with XPath 1.0:

```
translate(normalize-space(//ul)," ",",")
```

returns "office,space".

To add the last coma :

```
concat(translate(normalize-space(//ul)," ",","),",")
```

[image: XPath check]

returns "office,space,".

EDIT : With the website link you posted, use this one-liner to get what you want :

```
translate(normalize-space(//div[@class="container-fluid"]/ul)," ",",")
```

Output :

```
People,Space,Women,Friends,Communication,Group,Support,Community,Beautiful,Unity,Gender,Movement,Gathering,Copy,Rights,Feminist,Empower,Supporting,Copy,space,Empowering
```

It still needs some corrections (remove the undesired "," between Copy and space). If you need something fully automatic and since you have to use XPath 1.0 (no replace function), you can try :

```
translate(normalize-space(translate(//div[@class="container-fluid"]/ul," ",""))," ",",")
```

Output (Copy space are now merged) :

```
People,Space,Women,Friends,Communication,Group,Support,Community,Beautiful,Unity,Gender,Movement,Gathering,Copy,Rights,Feminist,Empower,Supporting,Copyspace,Empowering
```

Otherwise, just use :

```
//ul[@class="tags expandable"]//a/text()
```

And add the comas with the programming language you want.

Comment: unfortunately, it is not working. you can check it here http://xpather.com/

Comment: It does work. Xpather displays the result in the top right corner. Check it on https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester.

Comment: thank you, I am not using XML, I use this to scrape html, can you test it in this URL, I couldn't run in this URL https://www.freepik.com/free-photo/back-view-group-best-friends-holding-each-other_7089997.htm